# Firebase CLI suddenly ignoring environment variables on Functions deployment

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I have a Firebase code project with Functions meant to be deployed to multiple Firebase projects over multiple regions.

I used to set the deployment region like this:

```js
return functions
        .region(process.env.REGION)
        // ...
```

and used this command to deploy:

```
$ REGION=us-central1 firebase deploy --only functions
```

it worked like a charm until recently. Now it seems to completely ignore **REGION=us-central1** even if I **export** it before I run **firebase deploy**.

**EDIT 2022-06-13 - Possible solution**

I changed the code to dump the contents of process.env to a file during deployment. This is what I got:

```
{
  "FIREBASE_CONFIG": "{\"projectId\":\"REDACTED\",\"storageBucket\":\"REDACTED.appspot.com\",\"locationId\":\"us-central\"}",
  "GCLOUD_PROJECT": "REDACTED",
  "CLOUD_RUNTIME_CONFIG": "{REDACTED}",
  "__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING": "REDACTED"
}
```

so definitely is not the same list of variables I have in my local environment.

I could use the `locationId` from `FIREBASE_CONFIG` to get the target location, or `CLOUD_RUNTIME_CONFIG` (it contains the dump of the functions `.config()` object, so I could set the target there).
I also believe that I could use the `.env` and `.env.{project alias or ID}` files and their contents would be available in process.env at deployment time.

As per Osvaldo López's suggestion, here are some other details:

- Running on MacOS
- No errors are reported
- No recent changes to the CLI

Any input would be very welcome! Thanks.

Comment: Where are you running your CLI? Windows, Linux, Mac, WSL for Windows, Cloud Shell, VC Code over a particular OS…? Do you have any errors or log output? Have you recently made any change in your CLI configuration? Please update your post with this or other relevant information.

Comment: @OsvaldoLópez thank you for your suggestion, I just updated the post.

Comment: Which Firebase CLI version do you have? There are some recent updates related to [Firebase CLI v11.0.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/releases#cli_v11-0-0) that may produce your issue. Have you recently run `firebase init`? If you run it again for any Firebase service, the command will overwrite the corresponding section of the `firebase.json` file back to the default configuration for that service. On the other hand, if your update solves your issue, feel free to post it as an answer.

Comment: Did you solve this? Trying the same thing but I `ENVIRONMENT=development` is not picked up after calling `ENVIRONMENT=development firebase deploy --only functions`.